# sorting array of pointers in c++ using lambdas

Tags: c++, lambda

I am trying to write sorting template function to make it work with custom classes.

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct test
{
    int value;
    test(int a) : value(a){};
    void print() { printf("the value is : %d", value); };
};

template <class T>
void bubblesort(T *m_data, size_t size, bool (*cmp)(const T &l, const T &r))
{
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < size; i++)

        for (uint32_t j = 1; j < size - i; j++)

            if (cmp(m_data[j - 1], m_data[j]))
            {
                T temp = m_data[j];
                m_data[j] = m_data[j - 1];
                m_data[j - 1] = temp;
            }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<test> arr;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        arr.emplace_back(i);

    std::vector<test *> arr1;
    for (auto &i : arr)
        arr1.emplace_back(&i);

    bubblesort<test>(&arr[0], arr.size(), [](const test &l, const test &r) { return l.value < r.value; });

    // bubblesort<test*>(&arr1[0], arr1.size(), [](const test *&l, const test *&r) { return l->value < r->value; });

    for (auto i : arr)
        printf("%d\n", i.value);
}
```

My question is how do you `sort` arr1 using the `bubblesort` function above? What kind of modification do I have to make in my code to be able to do so?

uncommenting the bubblesort line gives error

```
 error: invalid user-defined conversion from 'main()::<lambda(const test*&, const test*&)>' to 'bool (*)(test* const&, test* const&)' [-fpermissive]
[build]    48 |     bubblesort<test *>(&arr1[0], arr1.size(), [](const test *&l, const test *&r) { return l->value < r->value; });
```

Comment: There is no arr2 in your code.

Comment: sorry I corrected that in edit1.

Comment: Aside: `arr.data()` is preferred over `&arr[0]`. If you have any discretion about the parameters to bubblesort, consider templating on (forward) iterators

Comment: Would suggest to keep the interface kept tied to using `.begin()` and `.end()`. For types that are not standard containers (but are arrays that can be iterated over), `begin(A)` and `end(A)` works.

Comment: The line you commented out is almost correct, but remember that the type being sorted isn't `test` but `test*`.

Comment: Try to look at arr1 before sorting it. Does that look right to you? The loop that populates it should be `for (auto &i : arr)`

Comment: I corrected  ```for (auto i : arr1)```  to ```for (auto &i : arr)``` thanks to @dratenik.
@Someprogrammerdude, it didnot work.

Comment: if I uncomment the commented line it gives me error
```error: invalid user-defined conversion from 'main()::<lambda(const test*&, const test*&)>' to 'bool (*)(test* const&, test* const&)' [-fpermissive]
[build]    48 |     bubblesort<test *>(&arr1[0], arr1.size(), [](const test *&l, const test *&r) { return l->value < r->value; });```

Comment: In the error message, pay close attention to what's actually `const`... The type `const test *` (or its equivalent `test const*`) is different from `test* const`. Because `const T&` (or the equivalent `T const&`) it's the `test*` that is `const`. One reason I favor trailing `const` since it makes such things easier to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function has the wrong type; `T` is `test*`, so you need `test* const&` - "reference to const pointer to `test`" - as the error message says.
(`const test*&` is "reference to pointer to const `test`.)

Answer (score 2):

Your solution cannot work with templates...it cannot deduce the parameters type.

Consider modifying your code as follow:

```
struct test
{
    int value;
    explicit test(int a) : value(a) {};
    void print() { printf("the value is : %d", value); };
};

template <class T, class _cmp>
void bubblesort(T *m_data, size_t size, _cmp cmp)
{
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < size; i++)

        for (uint32_t j = 1; j < size - i; j++)

            if (cmp(m_data[j - 1], m_data[j]))
            {
                T temp = m_data[j];
                m_data[j] = m_data[j - 1];
                m_data[j - 1] = temp;
            }
}


int main()
{
    
    std::vector<test> arr;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        arr.emplace_back(i);

    
    std::vector<test *> arr1;
    for (auto i : arr)
        arr1.emplace_back(&i);

    bubblesort<test>(&arr[0], arr.size(), [](const test &l, const test &r) -> bool { return l.value < r.value; });
    bubblesort<test*>(&arr1[0], arr1.size(), [](const test* l, const test* r) -> bool { return l->value < r->value; });

    for (auto i : arr)
        printf("%d\n", i.value);
}
```

Comment: It is worth noting the pointers in `arr1` point to expired a temporary variable and dereferencing such pointers in the lambda is UB.

Comment: @Qumby: yes, I didn't manage the problem with arr1 values..

Comment: how does this work? Does lambda get converted into some sort of class or something?